# Count html elements in ajax returned data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a jquery $.ajax call that returns a set of html from data.html which is like;

```
<div class="blah"><li>test</li></div>
<div class="blah"><li>test</li></div>
<div class="blah"><li>test</li></div>
<div class="blah"><li>test</li></div>
```

I'd like to count the amount of elements that have a class of .blah and i'm not sure how to do this.

I've tried:

```
data.html.getElementsByClassName('blah').length
```

but that obviously doesn't work!

Any suggestions gratefully received!!

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('blah').length` almost there

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7abrktLv/

Comment: I can't use document as the data is in ajax "data.html". I know i can do that if it's in the document already!

Comment: Is `data` an `object` ? , having a property named `html` ? , which contains string including `<div class="blah"><li>test</li></div>` ? Can include full response from `$.ajax()` call at Question ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Off-topic:The permitted parent element for a `li` element is `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<menu>` element.

Comment: Thanks @vohuman but that is just sample code, it's not what is actually returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass)

```js
var data = {};
data.html = '<div class="blah item item-wrapper print"></div>'
            + '<div class="blah item item-wrapper digital"></div>';

var len = $.grep($.parseHTML(data.html), function(el, i) {
  return $(el).hasClass("blah")
}).length;

$("body").html(len);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting 0 from my code, but i know there are 12 elements.

Comment: @John Can include response from `$.ajax()` at original post ? ,  create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, the issue is that the elements have other class names as well, so, <div class="blah item item-wrapper print"></div><div class="blah item item-wrapper digital"></div> Sorry, i should have added that to the code sample :(

Comment: _" but i know there are 12 elements"_ If `html` is reflected above, would be _24_ elements having `blah` `class` http://jsfiddle.net/o95x6xy3/1/ ? Difficult to verify correct `length` that should be returned without view of full response from `$.ajax()`

Comment: Those are two divs at the same level, not one div within another.

Comment: See updated post.  `js` at http://jsfiddle.net/o95x6xy3/1/ should return `length` of elements having `blah` class .

Comment: You are brilliant :) Thanks very much indeed for your patience with me!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using either `.filter()` or `.find()`, depending on the exact format of your returned HTML. If the format is is exactly as you have stated, then the following should work:

```
$.get("data.html", function(data) {
  var length = $(data).filter(".blah").length;
});
```

If there is some sort of wrapper element around your items with class `blah`, then you would use `.find()`:

```
$.get("data.html", function(data) {
  var length = $(data).find(".blah").length;
});
```

Comment: The data is in data.html rather than just data but if i try $(data.html).filter(".blah").length i get undefined expression error. Any ideas why?

Comment: data is the object and html is the property of type string that contains the html. I'm having no luck just using data. The code you are giving me is not going to work as the html content is in data.html

Comment: I don't see how $.get is involved on data that is already returned. Essentially, data.html is the data returned from a $.get that has already been performed.

Comment: So you've already stored the resulting html in a variable? Assuming that variable is named `x` then the following code should work: `$(x).filter(".blah").length`

Comment: I have tried that, but i get unexpected expression from it.

Comment: Then you likely have bad HTML in your variable. Can you post the exact contents of the variable or link to it?

Comment: After looking over your question again It occurs to me that you may have a naming problem, or perhaps you are trying to reference a property that doesn't exist. Specifically when you mention `data.html`. It's not really clear what `data` is in your question, but the `.html` part is most likely incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

$('.blah','context').length

Replace context by object in which you want to search